# Discord.js 'ReferenceError: require is not defined'

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require('./config.json');
```

I checked other question they contain problems regarding require(discord.js) [ye no '' between to make a string]
But that is not the problem I have for some reason my terminal responds with

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
                ^

ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at file:///C:/Users/tee-hee/Documents/Bots/Darkness/main.js:1:17
    at ModuleJob.run (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:140:23)
    at async Loader.import (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:165:24)
    at async Object.loadESM (internal/process/esm_loader.js:68:5
```

For some reason I have to reinstall node again to fix it this is the 10th time this is happening also this happens right after I deploy the code with ES6 method.
Don't know what to do
I tried reinstalling discord.js : npm i discord.js

Same thing happened so please help me.
Also don't give me the js is for server wide bla bla BS
It worked fine like 2 minutes ago.

Comment: May be an issue with your build pipeline? did you try `import discord from 'discord.js';`?

Comment: Try `npm i express` in your terminal

Answer (score 2):

The file containing the `require` statement is being treated as an ECMAScript module (which supports `import` and `export`) instead of a CommonJS module (which supports `require` and `module.exports`).

You can tell because, aside from the error, the loader module is in the `esm` directory.

Edit your `package.json` file so [the `type` field](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_type) says `"type": "commonjs"` and **not** `"type": "module"`.